# How do I delete an object using RestKit?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I want to delete Orphaned items on my app. So I did this :

```
for (Card *c in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects) {
   BOOL result = NO;
   for (Card * remove_card in remoteResultArray) {
      if ([remove_card.id intValue] == [c.id intValue]) {
          result = YES;
       }
   }
   if (!result) {
        NSLog(@"%@",c.id);
        [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext deleteObject:c];
   }
 }
 [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext save:&error];
```

In fact it works, my records disappear but when i reboot the app, they are here again. How do I delete a record with restkit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreManagedObjectContext instead.

Or implementing this behavior is described here: http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html under "Fetch Request Blocks and Deleting Orphaned Objects.